# SQL: Get Random 4 signs long String from value field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to get random 4 signs out of a Value with SQL?

For Example:

| ID | TextValue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Policestation |
| 2 | HarrypotterDVDs |
| 3 | Dummyfiredepartment |

Out of each Value in textvalue column, I need to pick 4 random signs out of it.
Means:

Value:

Poli**cest**ation  => Randomstring: cest

**Harr**ypotterDVDs         => Randomstring: Harr

Dummyfiredepar**tmen**t     => Randomstring: tmen

Is there a SQLFunction for that?

Comment: `rand()`..? Does it matter if if it's the *same* 4 characters for each row? Ie if you picked a random number to start and picked 4 characters from each eg `lice` and `rryp` and `mmfi` - still random for each row...?

Comment: What should the result be if the value is less than 4 characters?

Comment: Perhaps `SUBSTRING(YourValue, CAST(ROUND(RAND() * LEN(YourValue) - 4) AS int), 4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a truly random result picked per row for each execution you could do something like the following. Use a numbers/tally table (here a CTE) and select a random starting position using `newid()`

```
with seq as 
  (select top(20) n = Row_Number() over(order by (select null)) from master.dbo.spt_values)
select Substring(textvalue,IsNull(r,1),4)
from t
outer apply (
    select top (1) n
    from seq
    where n <= Len(textvalue)-3
    order by NewId()
)v(r);
```

Comment: Dear Stu, this is working like a charm! This is exactly what I was looking for. I already did read about the rand() function - but as far as i can see it, it only works with numbers? Anyway, this is great! thank you!